How to rename projectname.exe.config file to userdefined?
I have got a project in Visual Studio 2022 using C#. It uses an external library I included to that project. Now I want all dlls to be in a separate folder, so I need the projectname.exe.config file.
My question: how do I rename this file to e.g. application.config, but still have my app able to read it?
When I looked up on the internet I wasn't able to find anything useful.
Changing the assembly name resulted in the exe also change its name. But that's not what I want.

Why do you want to do that in the first place? You get no benefit and have to replicate all the build and transformation functionality. DLLs have no config files, they read their settings from the application config file. If each assembly reads its settings from a separate section, you can put those sections in th e application's config file. You can apply transformations per section

App.config is a file in XML format. You can change the name of App.config.
Set App.config file properties: Copy to Output Directory -> Copy if newer.
E.g.
App.config -> UserDefined.config.
Also set  config file in the code:
 using System.Configuration;//install System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager nuget package.

......
ExeConfigurationFileMap confileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
confileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "UserDefined.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(confileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string value=config.AppSettings.Settings["YourCustomSettings"].Value;

Update:

I want all dlls to be in a separate folder

projectname.exe.config is evaluated by program start from the runtime.
You can use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve instead of  application.config file.  In this way you can load DLLs from any path, not just subfolders.
Replace absolute path <your DLL folder> with yours.
For Console app:
Add a static function with   [ModuleInitializer]. .NET 6 or greater:
 [ModuleInitializer]
 public static void Initialize()
 {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
     {
         string fileName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
         string assemblyPath = Path.Combine("<your DLL folder>", fileName);
         var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
         return assembly;
     };
 }

For Winform,  in main():
 [STAThread]
 static void Main()
 {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
         {
             string fileName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
             string assemblyPath = Path.Combine("<your DLL folder>", fileName);
             var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
             return assembly;
         };
//
     ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
     Application.Run(new Form1());
 }

In addition, relative path to absolute path, e.g.  exe folder\lib:
  string exeDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
  string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(exeDirectory, "lib", fileName);
  var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);

For .NET Framework Console project, call AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve in the static constructor:
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.IO;
......
 internal class Program
 {
      static  Program()
     {
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
         {

             string fileName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
             string exeDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
             string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(exeDirectory, "lib", fileName);
             var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
             return assembly;
         };

     }
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        //call library code here

     }


I need this file for my DLL libraries that are in a different folder. By renaming this file it didn't work

I edited my answer. Please check it.

This answer shows how to dynamically load assemblies, not how to load config files at all
